# Functions in $L_p[0,1)$ grow at most polynomially

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lp-spaces

I just stumbled across the John-Nirenberg inequality which bounds the growth of functions in the BMO space. So I got curious whether such a bound on the growth also exists for $L_p$ functions. Let me state the problem:

Let $f:[0,1)\to\mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function. Does it hold that $f\in L_p[0,1)$ if and only if there exists an $\varepsilon>0$ and a $C\ge 0$ such that \begin{equation}\label{eqn}
\lambda(\{|f|\ge x\})\le Cx^{-(p+\varepsilon)}
\end{equation}

where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure?

One direction is easy. Assume that the inequality holds. Then

\begin{eqnarray*}
\|f\|_p^p &=& \int_0^1f(x)^pdx=p\int_0^\infty\lambda(\{|f|\ge u\})u^{p-1}du\\
&=& p\int_0^1\lambda(\{|f|\ge u\})u^{p-1}du+p\int_1^\infty\lambda(\{|f|\ge u\})u^{p-1}du\\
&\le& 1+ p\int_1^\infty Cu^{-(1+\varepsilon)}du<\infty.
\end{eqnarray*}

How does one show the other direction of the equivalence? Or, if the equivalence is false, is there a similar statement bounding the growth of functions in $L_p[0,1)$?

Comment: I don't see why you're assuming you would always need an $x^\epsilon$ of room. Like why can't you have $\lambda(\{|f| \ge x\}) \le C x^{-p}\log^{-2}(x)$? Your proof would still go through. And I think something like $f(y) = y^{-1/p}\log^{2}(\frac{1}{y})$ or something would give the $\log$ instead of a power of $x$.

Comment: In any event, I'm pretty sure any form of the conjecture you would want to make is unfortunately false